# Sankey chart in R with networkD3

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to create a sankey chart using networkD3 in R.

[image]

I tried to create a minimal example but already failed at the code. I tried but did not even get three correct columns to display:

```
#Load required library
library(networkD3)

# Create a data frame with the nodes and links
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Asia", "Europe", "NA", "Asia", "Europe", "NA", "Asia", "Europe", "NA"))
links <- data.frame(source = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                    target = c(3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                    value = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1))

# Create the Sankey diagram
sankey <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

# Display the Sankey diagram
print(sankey)
```

Directionally it works, however, it does not add all flows on the second level. Further when adding e.g. flows from NA to NA, a strangely looking circle appears.
[image]

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you describe what errors you get or what is wrong with the output? Maybe the output of `utils::sessionInfo()` so we can see what versions of R and packages you're using?

Comment: I updated the post. I'm using R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)

Comment: There are 9 links/flows specified in your links data frame, and all 9 links are shown in the 2nd plot you posted. You have 9 nodes specified in your nodes data frame, but only 6 of them (0-5) are referenced in your links data frame, hence the 3 node names not connected to anything in the plot. I don't see the circle you are mentioning.

Comment: Thanks. I meant circles such as in the following instance:

nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Asia", "Europe", "NA", "Asia", "Europe", "NA", "Asia", "Europe", "NA"))
links <- data.frame(source = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                    target = c(3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 0, 1),
                    value = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1))

# Create the Sankey diagram
sankey <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

Comment: The "circles" in that example are circular links which are specified in the links data frame, e.g. row 4 of links 1->4 and row 9 of links 4->1 (Europe (1) -> Europe (4) -> Europe (1))... and also line 6 of the data frame 2->2 (NA (2) -> NA (2))

Comment: I get that. However, I would like to have the flow e.g. from Europe to Europe to Europe from left to middle to right column (as in the initial screenshot). Is that possible?

Comment: Then you must specify each unique node that you want to appear in your nodes data frame, and your links data frame must specify each unique link you want to appear.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you give a code example please?

Comment: library(networkD3); nodes <- data.frame(name = c("E1", "E2", "E3")); links <- data.frame(source = c(0, 1), target = c(1, 2), value = c(1, 1)); sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value")